# Flutter: What are the ways of making "lists" without having its own scroll?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, mobile, flutter-layout

In my Flutter app, I have a `ListView` inside a `ListView`. Please check below

```
 ListView(
   children: < Widget > [
    //Stack Widget
    //More Widgets
    Container(
     height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
     child: ListView.builder(
      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(), //Disable Scrolling
      itemCount: 100,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
       return Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10, left: 10, right: 10),
        child: _createAdvertisement(),
       );
      },
     ),
    ),
   ],
  );
```

There are 100 items in the second `ListView` and I used `physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()` to stop it from scrolling. I do not want this to scroll because the top `ListView` can scroll the entire page, so I want the content in the second `ListView` to be added to the bottom of the page. User can scroll the entire page up, to see the content below.

However my trick of using `physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()` didnt work, instead it limited the number of elements the `ListView` is going to generate. As a result, now I have less than 10 items in that listview, instead of 100.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add "shrinkWrap: true," and remove "height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,".

```
ListView(
  children: <Widget>[
    Text("1"),
    Text("2"),
    Container(
      child: ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,  // add this line.
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(), //Disable Scrolling
        itemCount: 100,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10, left: 10, right: 10),
            child: Text("test"),
          );
        },
      ),
    ),
    Text("3"),
  ],
),
```

[image: top image]
[image: bottom image]